# R: reverse reshape2's melt() on n-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, reshape2, melt

I've got a 3-dimensional array in R that I can use `melt()` on to produce a long `data.frame`:

```
library(abind)
library(reshape2)
a = matrix(1:4, nrow=2, ncol=2)
x = abind(a, a, along=3)
y = melt(x)
y
```

which yields:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3 value
1    1    1    1     1
2    2    1    1     2
3    1    2    1     3
4    2    2    1     4
5    1    1    2     1
6    2    1    2     2
7    1    2    2     3
8    2    2    2     4
```

How can I transform the data back to the original array? It should work with `acast`, but I can't find the right arguments for it:

```
y['idx'] = rownames(y)
acast(y, idx~Var1+Var2+Var3, value.var='value') # does not work this way
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple dimensions, you need some more tildes (if I understood your question correctly):

```
acast(y, Var1 ~ Var2 ~ Var3)
# , , 1
# 
#   1 2
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
# 
# , , 2
# 
#   1 2
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
```

---

To generalize this behavior, you can try constructing a `formula` with `paste`:

```
Form <- as.formula(paste(grep("^Var", names(y), value=TRUE), 
                         collapse = " ~ "))
acast(y, Form)
```

Comment: ...and it takes the one remaining column as the values.

Comment: One thing, actually: is it possible to generalize this for `Var1~Var2~...~VarN` without using `eval()`?